# How can I obtain the bitrate of a video from a command line in Linux?

Tags: linux, video, xvid

What is a good command line tool to get the video bitrate of a divx or xvid avi file for linux?

Comment: ffplayer shows the current nitrate while playing video.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use MPlayer to get that information.

```
$ mplayer -vo null -ao null -identify -frames 0 foo.avi
```

In particular, you want the `-identify` option.  The option `-frames 0` tells it not to playback the file, and `-vo null -ao null` give it null drivers for video & audio (so you can use this command via SSH or another non-X-enabled terminal).

You can combine this with `grep` or other tools to pull out the specific line you want:

```
$ mplayer -vo null -ao null -identify -frames 0 foo.avi | grep kbps
VIDEO:  [XVID]  512x384  24bpp  29.970 fps  990.9 kbps (121.0 kbyte/s)
```

The full output looks like this:

```
$ mplayer -vo null -ao null -identify -frames 0 foo.avi
MPlayer dev-SVN-r26940 (C) 2000-2007 MPlayer Team
CPU: [hw dependent]
CPUflags:  [hw dependent]
Compiled with runtime CPU detection.

Playing foo.avi.
AVI file format detected.
ID_VIDEO_ID=0
[aviheader] Video stream found, -vid 0
ID_AUDIO_ID=1
[aviheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1
VIDEO:  [XVID]  512x384  24bpp  29.970 fps  990.9 kbps (121.0 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 Software: transcode-1.0.2
ID_CLIP_INFO_NAME0=Software
ID_CLIP_INFO_VALUE0=transcode-1.0.2
ID_CLIP_INFO_N=1
ID_FILENAME=foo.avi
ID_DEMUXER=avi
ID_VIDEO_FORMAT=XVID
ID_VIDEO_BITRATE=990928
ID_VIDEO_WIDTH=512
ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT=384
ID_VIDEO_FPS=29.970
ID_VIDEO_ASPECT=0.0000
ID_AUDIO_FORMAT=85
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=135104
ID_AUDIO_RATE=0
ID_AUDIO_NCH=0
ID_LENGTH=1288.95
ID_SEEKABLE=1
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
Selected video codec: [ffodivx] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-4)
==========================================================================
ID_VIDEO_CODEC=ffodivx
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [mp3lib] MPEG layer-2, layer-3
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 128.0 kbit/8.33% (ratio: 16000->192000)
ID_AUDIO_BITRATE=128000
ID_AUDIO_RATE=48000
ID_AUDIO_NCH=2
Selected audio codec: [mp3] afm: mp3lib (mp3lib MPEG layer-2, layer-3)
==========================================================================
AO: [null] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
ID_AUDIO_CODEC=mp3
Starting playback...

Exiting... (End of file)
```

Comment: ps.  the mplayer manpage is a *nightmare* ...

Comment: For those unaware, this is essentially what midentify.sh does, the script which ships with mplayer.

Comment: The flags need to be updated. I get 'invalid option -- 'o'
 in Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 27):

ffmpeg works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i file.avi
```

Comment: ffmpeg prevails where mplayer fails.

Comment: Some recent distributions (Debian, Ubuntu 14) dropped ffmpeg and instead shipped its libav fork, so you might need to install `libav-tools` and run `avconv -i` instead of `ffmpeg -i`

Comment: Can you please guide me that what is video bitrate using following sample output?

Input #0, flv, from 'mi-cc-03-bed_and_breakfast.flv':
  Duration: 00:00:18.7, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
  Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 480x360, 29.92 fps(r)
  Stream #0.1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, 64 kb/s
Must supply at least one output file

Comment: Zain, you pasted output with a total bitrate of 128 kb/s.  "bitrate: 64 kb/s" in both video and audio sections.

Comment: A relevant remark is that the output of `ffmpeg -i file.avi` goes to `stderr`, not to `stdout`. So, to `grep` it in  one has to do  `ffmpeg -i file.avi 2>&1 | grep -i kbps`

Answer (score 8):

### **For video files:**

Get exactly the video bitrate via **mediainfo**:
`$ mediainfo --Output='Video;%BitRate%' '/MY/MEDIA/FILE.MP4'`
or in Kbps:
`$ mediainfo --Output='Video;%BitRate/String%'`

Get exactly the audio bitrate via **mediainfo** in bps:
`$ mediainfo --Output='Audio;%BitRate%' '/MY/MEDIA/FILE.MP4'`
or in Kbps:
`$ mediainfo --Output='Audio;%BitRate/String%' '/MY/MEDIA/FILE.MP4'`

### **For audio files:**

`$ mediainfo --Inform='General;%OverallBitRate%' '/MY/MEDIA/FILE.MP3'`
or in Kbps:
`$ mediainfo --Inform='General;%OverallBitRate/String%' '/MY/MEDIA/FILE.MP3'`

`--Inform` option works same as `--Output` here

Answer (score 6):

```
avprobe -show_streams file.avi
```

Comment: To show the overall bit rate, you'd be better off using `-show_format`, or even better (on *nix) `avprobe -show_format file.avi | grep bit_rate`. The same syntax will also work for ffprobe.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another tool that does the same thing: `tcprobe`, which is part of the `transcode` package.  Use the `-i` switch to get an info dump from the file (sample output from the same file as in the `mplayer` example):

```
$ tcprobe -i foo.avi
[tcprobe] RIFF data, AVI video
[avilib] V: 29.970 fps, codec=XVID, frames=38630, width=512, height=384
[avilib] A: 48000 Hz, format=0x55, bits=16, channels=2, bitrate=128 kbps,
[avilib]    53707 chunks, 21768720 bytes, VBR
[tcprobe] summary for foo.avi, (*) = not default, 0 = not detected
import frame size: -g 512x384 [720x576] (*)
       frame rate: -f 29.970 [25.000] frc=4 (*)
      audio track: -a 0 [0] -e 48000,16,2 [48000,16,2] -n 0x55 [0x2000] (*)
                   bitrate=128 kbps
           length: 38630 frames, frame_time=33 msec, duration=0:21:28.954
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to get same info but just that data to use it in a bash loop .. and I've got it ! Using FFPROBE !

FFPROBE : hide_banner : hide header info, loglevel 0 give us only our required info, select_streams specify which stream (video) we're working on , show_entries let us specify which data specifically we want

fer@FerPC:~/Downloads/TEMP$ ffprobe -hide_banner -loglevel 0  -of flat -i 'Eng_Sub_EP.1_1_4.mkv' -select_streams v   -show_entries 'format=bit_rate'

you get :  format.bit_rate="1085360"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy-paste bash answer using avprobe (which comes with avconv and maybe ffmpeg) in case you want only the number (for further scripting)

```
function bitrate () { avprobe -show_format "$1" 2> /dev/null | grep "bit_rate" | sed 's/.*bit_rate=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g'; }
```

It works like this. This line gets info about the file (removing extra info on stdout):

```
avprobe -show_format test.mp4 2> /dev/null
```

Then `grep` selects the line which mentions bitrate

```
grep "bit_rate"
```

From which `sed` then extracts the bitrate (in bits/second)

```
sed 's/.*bit_rate=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/g';
```

Long story short, copy the function in the first line and then you can do

```
$ bitrate test.mp4
593567
```

(that's not a high-quality video, 593 kb/s, since bitrate uses 1000 instead of 1024 apparently)