# Codec for MPEG2 file on 64 bit Windows 7 system

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, images, codec

Can someone point me to a 64-bit MPEG2 codec for Windows 7? I am trying to read some big MPEG2 files using MATLAB's [VideoReader](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html;jsessionid=8f089579e191c041129ab63fc9bd). I get an error saying I should install a MPEG-2 codec, but I haven't been able to find a 64-bit codec for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about converting the video to another format (or would that potentially change the pixels too much). 
If this would be an option for you, you could use ffmpeg cli: http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg
It is very fast and easy to convert various video files, while preserving the original quality.

Comment: That is a great suggestion. Quality isn't too important - I just need to see the orientation of the main object in the video. I found this example of how to convert MPEG-2 to MPEG-1 which I hope will work!  http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/convert-mpeg2-to-mpeg1-td938360.html

Comment: Wow, that worked like a charm. You solved a week long problem for me. Turned out the command format should be,     ffmpeg -i myMpeg2File.mpg -target ntsc-vcd -y myMpeg1File.mpg

Comment: That's nice to hear! Gl!