# How to determine video stream size

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

I want to determine stream size(not the video size) and using the following ffprobe command to make this work

```
ffprobe -v error -count_packets -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=size my_input_file_name
```

But this is not working, and producing no output, Can anybody point the issue with this command

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perform a null mux.

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f null -
```

The final readout will have that info:

```
video:0kB audio:2684kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Can this not be done only using ffprobe? Like analysing the packets or frames show_frames,show_packets output?

Comment: You want a sum, not individual packet info, so no.

Comment: If I sum up the size attribute of -show_packets command then do you think this will work?
ffprobe -v error -show_packets -select_streams a -show_entries packet=size -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 video.mp4

Comment: Ok, that should work. Remove the `-show_packets`; that's unnecessary clutter.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple and immediate way of obtaining detailed info about a media file, try [mediainfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Download) utility. It will specify the video/audio stream sizes too.

`mediainfo MyFilename.mp4` for basic info

`mediainfo --fullscan MyFilename.mp4` for more detailed info

Output example:

```
~> mediainfo MyFilename.mp4
General
Complete name                            : ~/MyFilename.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2)
File size                                : 1.03 GiB
Duration                                 : 3 h 9 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 781 kb/s
Encoded date                             : UTC 2021-10-08 21:36:28
Tagged date                              : UTC 2021-10-08 21:36:28

Video
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L4
Format settings                          : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, Reference frames        : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=48
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 3 h 9 min
Duration_LastFrame                       : -48 ms
Bit rate                                 : 712 kb/s
Nominal bit rate                         : 1 000 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 8.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.043
Stream size                              : 963 MiB (91%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 148 r2M 3713d6c
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=1 / deblock=0:0:0 / analyse=0:0 / me=dia / subme=0 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=0 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=0 / 8x8dct=0 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=0 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=48 / keyint_min=4 / scenecut=0 / intra_refresh=0 / rc=abr / mbtree=0 / bitrate=1000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=20 / qpmax=51 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=0
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2021-10-08 21:36:28
Tagged date                              : UTC 2021-10-08 21:36:28
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 3 h 9 min
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 68.3 kb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 89.1 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 16.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 15.625 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 92.5 MiB (9%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2021-10-08 21:36:28
Tagged date                              : UTC 2021-10-08 21:36:28
```

See original post and other tools [here](https://superuser.com/questions/595177/how-to-retrieve-video-file-information-from-command-line-under-linux/595205#595205).

Comment: It doesn't show stream size if the file doesn't advertise it in a tag.

Comment: All that's doing is reading tags. If you re-encode the MKV file without clearing out the metadata, you'll receive the wrong information. I've had `mediainfo` tell me the audio stream was bigger than the entire file bc of that.