# How to find out characteristics of video captured from a webcam in linux

Tags: linux

I'd like to see from command line all informations pertaining to a given video file, including length, quality, bitrate, resolution, audio and video formats, number and language of audio streams and subtitles, and so on; the more, the best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve video file information from command line under Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/595177/how-to-retrieve-video-file-information-from-command-line-under-linux)

Comment: Quick answer: Try using `exiftool` or `ffmpeg -i`. Each should work but each presents the details differently and with different depth.

Comment: The video is captured by the FPGA programmed as a UVC device and I need to extract the details of the video that has been compressed by my FPGA

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mediainfo](https://pkgs.org/download/mediainfo) to output majority of the information anyone would require of a video file; at least I would imagine so.  Simply:

```
mediainfo "<inputfile>"
```

I once had to frequently setup ffmpeg commands in a shell script setup to run while away, and a zenity window made this alot easier as well.  I used:

```
mediainfo "<inputfile>" | zenity --text-info
```

So then I could hightlight the info and just drag and drop it to nano, on the terminal window directly.  Worked great.