# How to open a file with .ghi extension?

Tags: file-extension

Does anybody know how to open or convert to an more common format this type of file?

Google says that this may be an configuration file but the person who provided this file says this is a record from a camera.

Comment: Your best chance it to go back to whomever provided the video and ask them if the camera or software program that they used can export to a different format. I have searched extensively, and can find nothing. Btw, "how to" questions belong here, but it you have a "is there an app to ..." question, then there is also our [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) sister site

Comment: Windows relates on file extension, while most other OS to use the header. You can copy that file on a linux machine and run `file video.ghi` on it.

Comment: You can also use mediainfo: https://superuser.com/questions/595177/how-to-retrieve-video-file-information-from-command-line-under-linux

Comment: Try to open it in VLC.